# Meteor JS: How do I access the previous record in a collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a list of messages in a collection. When rendering each message in a collection, I'd like to compare the timestamps and userIds of the message to the previous message. However, I am not sure how to access the data to do the comparison. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here's are my templates:

```
<template name="messageList">
  <ul>
    {{#each messages}}
      {{>messageItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="messageItem">
  <li>
    <p class="{{nameVisibility}}">{{userName}}</p>
    <p>{{body}}</p>
  </li>
</template>
```

Here is my helpers file:

```
Template.messageItem.helpers({
  nameVisibility: function() {

    //Not sure how to query the previous message in relation to this one.
    previousMessage = Messages.findOne(...);
    if (this.userId != previousMessage.userId) {
      return false;
    else {
      return "hideName";
    }  
  }
});
```

Comment: Either store the previous result somewhere while looping over the cursor, or fetch the entire query into an array.  For "previous" to make sense, there needs to be some sorting.  MongoDB does not impose an order.

Comment: The question is, do you actually have a "timestamp" property available in your "schema"? And if so are you always expecting these results to be "timestamp" ordered? If so the process is simple. If not and you are looking for "insertion order" then you are likely going to morn the fact the the proper MongoDB ObjectId is actually monotonic, which would reflect the insertion order. But unless you are explicitly using  default ObjectId's then what meteor replaces that with has come back to bite you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the other answer in this post, which is horribly inefficient and requires iterating over the entire Messages collection an extra time.

I think the best way to do this would be with regular jQuery in the `Template.messageItem.rendered` callback. You can find the previous element, use `UI.getElementData` to find its data, and either remove or add the username as appropriate. On Meteor 0.8.0+ (Blaze rendering engine), your edits will stick. Something like this:

```
Template.messageItem.rendered = function() {
  // this.firstNode is the <li> tag; .prev() grabs its previous sibling
  prevMessage = $(this.firstNode).prev();
  prevData = UI.getElementData(prevMessage[0]); // but make sure prevMessage[0] exists
  if (prevData.userName === this.data.userName)
    this.$(".username").remove(); // Make sure you put the ".username" class on the prefix
}
```

Comment: Well said in context, but do you have anything to add on monotonic ObjectId values, or lack of when replaced, that could add to this.

Comment: Confused as to how I would get the previous element via jQuery and then use UI.getElementData with it.

Comment: @Chanpory sure, added some example code. Not tested though, and you need to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: @AndrewMao makes a good point, I didn’t consider efficiency (I assumed that the query on the Messages collection was quite constrained, like one user’s most recent 100 messages or somesuch). But processing jQuery selectors on each message render is quite inefficient too. Perhaps a better solution still would be to add a transformation on the `.find` itself, that adds the `nameVisibility` attribute as appropriate; then you’re not iterating over the results after they’re returned, and no jQuery is required.

Comment: I did not know about this `transform` voodoo! Reading up on it now and it sounds great.

Comment: I agree with @GeoffreyBooth that the `transform` method is probably the right way to do this. Took a few tries for us to see it, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Preprocess the array you’re looping over:

```
Template.messageList.helpers({
  messages: function() {
    var i, j, messages;
    messages = Messages.find({}).fetch(); // Replace `{}` with your query
    for (i = 0, j = ret.length; i < j; i++) {
      if (messages[i-i] != null && messages[i].userId == messages[i-1].userId)
        messages[i].nameVisibility = "hideName";
    }
    return messages;
  }
});
```